# ArangoDB edge consistency when removing a document

Tags: arangodb

In ArangoDB, I have 2 documents linked by a edge 'uses':

```
A  ----uses--->  B
```

When I remove the document B in the collection:

- why the edge isn't removed and refers to a non-existent document?
- OR: why can I remove de document B if a edge uses it?

PS: When I remove the document B in the graph web interface, the edge is automatically removed.

ArangoDB version: 3.0.8

Answer (score 1):

To remove a document with edge consistency, you must use Graph API and not Document API.

ArangoJs:
https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs#graphvertexcollectionremove